# How to manage connections in compose for postgresql in bluemix?

Tags: postgresql, ibm-cloud, compose-db

We are using pgadmin with postgresql on bluemix and keep seeing connections from our web app and pgadmin just lingering. Is there a way to set postgresql on bluemix with a max connection time?

Is there a way to set it in bluemix itself on the service?

Comment: `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` maybe?

Comment: how to set this in bluemix?

Comment: If that is a regular Postgres version you can do: `alter system set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout ...` if you have superuser access (or  edit `postgresql.conf` of course).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you don't get superuser access with Compose databases.

Comment: @Johnson currently the feature to increase the max connection limit in Compose PostgreSQL - IBM Cloud - isn't available. Have you tried pgBouncer for connection pooling?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like no way to configure it in the bluemix postgresql side.

So in summary, we setup a PHP or Node app that uses pgbouncer which connects to our postgresql instance. Then we route all app connections to the pgbouncer app.